# shell_exec + mysqldump not working with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, shell-exec

I am trying to run mysqldump with shell_exec command with where condition.

```
$shell_result = shell_exec('mysqldump --op ctax91_db leads  --where="id  =  "a"   " |  gzip > Leads.sql.gz ');
```

i tried many options for changng quotes but it is not working .
also tried for  --where="id  = '"'a'" , but not working

please suggest

Comment: Have you tried to check for quoting issues? Why do you close the string `id = ` before that identifier?

Comment: Seems like escape issue 
`shell_exec('mysqldump --op ctax91_db leads  --where="id = \’a\’ " |  gzip > Leads.sql.gz ');`

Comment: tx for advice , tried working in same direction , this worked --  --where=' id  =  '\"'a'\"'